# Node.js versioning : difference between v4+ and v0.12.X

Tags: node.js

What's the difference between Node.js version >= 4.0.0 and versions 0.1.X to 0.12.X ?

On this page https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/, I understand that Node.js v4+ is a fusion between old Node.js and io.js. But v0.12.9 has been released on 2015-12-03, few months **after** v4.0.0 (2015-09-08).

So, are the 3 branches still active ? What's the difference between them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nodejs 4.x is the converged version of Node 0.12.x and io.js 3.x.  io.js was originally developed due to the conflict between Joyent and Nodejs team. Version 1.x was released in Jan 2015. You can see this [changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for the complete list of Nodejs releases.

Node.js team described when they announced this feature is that 2 different types of node.js versions will meet your node.js needs.

- **LTS** (Long Term Support, currently v.4.2.4) will have support and maintenance for at least 18 months. After 18 months have passed, it will transition into Maintenance mode which may last 12 months. So Long Term Support (often referred to as LTS) guarantees application developers a 30 month support cycle with specific versions of Node.js.
- **Stable** (currently v5.4.1) - will have support for approximately 8 months, with features/updates released more often. `Node.js v6` will eventually turn into a new LTS version that will have a similar support timeline to v4. In this way, we will have a new Stable version of Node.js every 6 months with every second one of these turning into an LTS line.

Node.js v0.10 and v0.12 are special cases in the LTS plan. v0.10 will go directly into maintenance in October, lasting for 12 months. v0.12 will have an initial LTS period of 6 months starting from October, followed by the requisite 12 months maintenance. `io.js` releases will not have official LTS or maintenance support.

Source:

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v5.0.0/

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/community/node-v5/

https://medium.com/@nodesource/essential-steps-long-term-support-for-node-js-8ecf7514dbd#.48y0ywbsp

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/COLLABORATOR_GUIDE.md

Comment: Thank you, but you don't totally answer my questions, especially "are the 3 branches still alive ?", still there are releases of Node 0.12 and io.js after the creation of Nodejs 4.X.

Comment: What does IMO means?

Comment: @Eria, `LTS` mean `Long Term Support`, so those three branches are still alive.

Comment: And so, what does "IMO" means ? Google already told me about the meaning of "LTS" ;)

Comment: Nice, but: "Long Term Support (often referred to as LTS) guarantees application developers a 30 month support cycle with specific versions of Node.js." - https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/COLLABORATOR_GUIDE.md  18 month is the period of _active_ maintenance, followed by 12 months of 'maintenance mode'. Where did you get the approx. 8 months for stable versions from?

Comment: @mklement0, in this [page](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v5.0.0/), `This new version of Node.js, however, will only be supported for 8 months, with a new major version, v6, being released in April 2016`, hope I got it correctly.